# jquery easyui,ie10,ie11,firefox,the default cursor position in input is at 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-easyui

I use jquery easyui to help me with the project. But there are problems when I use ie10,ie11 and the newest version of firefox to test the edit form.

When I used firefox and clicked the  ,which was focused, but the cursor position is 0,at the head of the input value.
When I used ie,I needed to double click to focus the  , and the position was same as firefox.

How to set the default cursor position at the end of input value ?

Answer (score 1):

you can bind a focus event to move the cursor to the end

```
// simple
<input onfocus="moveCursorToEnd(this)" />
// better to bind with jquery
$("input[type='text']").on("focus", function(){
   moveCursorToEnd(this);
});
// delegate
$("#form").on("focus", "input", function(){
   moveCursorToEnd(this);
});


function moveCursorToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: $("input[type='text']").on("focus", function(){
     var that = $(this);
     var value = that.val();
     that.val("");
     that.val(value);
});

Comment: This need to double click to focus the input with ie10 , ie11 and edge.

Comment: The focus event fires when the element is set focus - not when its clicked.  Your JQuery line above is the same as ( this.value = this.value; ) which may also move the cursor to the end is some cases.

Comment: I don't know why “ that.val("");  ” is neccessary. If I remove that ， the cursor would not move to end.  And I have solved the question in another way, remove draggable="false" or draggable="true" from the datagrid  .

Answer (score 0):

iconCls="icon-save" cache="false" resizable="true" modal="true" draggable="false" closed="true"

The data options of draggable should be removed.

like :
iconCls="icon-save" cache="false" resizable="true" modal="true" closed="true"